# jQuery: z-index not working for particular .this (NOT IE issue)

Tags: jquery, position, z-index

http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/ZjN6V/17/

So you double click one of the blocks, I want the background to fade, except the element clicked, I want to raise that one above the faderClass DIV.

But the .this selected won't take the z-index.
I tried everything.

I challenge you guys to get it to work... I think there's a general bug in this, having probably to do with relative/absolute...

Comment: i think that `z-index` works only in `absolute` position

Answer (score 1):

No matter what `z-index` you apply to the clicked div, it never comes on top of `.faderClass` because the container of the clicked div has a lower `z-index` than the `.faderClass`

Without calling `.faderClass` you can fadeOut the rest of the `blocky` divs and only keep the one that was clicked.